# Can Neo4j community edition start in warm up?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.0 community edition in rest server on ubuntu.
Every time a first query is slow response after startup the neo4j.
And remain queries which is same the first one are fast response. I guess this behavior is relative to cache. 
I tried to cache all primitives(node, rel, props) by following query. I executed the query using webadmin after stareted up neo4j server, but the first query performance didn't improve.

```
start n=node(*) match n--m return count(n)
```

or

```
match (n)-[r]-() return count(n)
```

All primitives size about 1.5GB, and my computer resource is enough.
my neo4j.properties is here:

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
all_stores_total_mapped_memory_size=1500M
eostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=150M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=600M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=10M

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=true

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
#node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#node_keys_indexable=name,age

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age

dump_configuration=true
```

Is there a way that neo4j communith edition startup with cache in worm up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Which version are you using?

They only way you can warm up your cache is to run your typical queries.

It is 3-fold

1. warm up the filesystem caches (mmio)
2. warm up the high-level caches (object-cache)
3. precompile the cypher queries that you will use so cypher has not to build them for the first user.

This query should help with warmup:

`match (n)-[r]-() return count(n)`

If you also want to load properties too you can add:

`match (n)-[r]-() where not has(n.foo) and not has(r.foo) return count(n)`

What do your typical queries that are slow look like?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0 stable community edition. I want to know to execute a query you taught after startup means caching filesystem or object-cache. And my typical query like this `"query" : "match (u:User{uid:{uid}})-[:READ]->(b:Book)<-[:READ]-(u2:User) with u2, count(u2) as user_rank order by user_rank desc limit 100 match u2-[:READ]->(b2:Book) with b2, count(b2) as rank order by rank desc limit 1000 match (u:User{uid:{uid}}) where not (b2)<-[:READ]-(u) return b2.name, rank order by rank desc limit 100"` I query with a parameter as uid.

Comment: My graph model sample is following link:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=27ke5p
Actual model contain 320K Books and 50K Users, and one user has about 10 read books.

Comment: My above query intends book recommendation by user similarity. I noticed using not pattern in where clause makes slow response time if its comparison nodes are large, so I choice using with clause for filtering nodes.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I can't understand this matter yet. please teach me something else. Thanks