# Cypher query taking extremely long time on Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have set up a Neo4J database that is roughly [19GB](http://cl.ly/image/2k2M3D1e2Y2m). The graph contains roughly 9 million nodes, 40 million properties, and 65 million relationships. The nodes are made up of people and titles. I have 1 relationship type, "IN." This is very similar to a large scale movie database example.

Running simple queries in order to find a particular node takes a very long amount of time and then when I want to run something a little more sophisticated, like a shortestPath, it takes even longer. Here are some example queries:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Tom Cruise"}) return p

MATCH p = shortestPath( (from:Person {id: 12345})-[*]-(to:Person {id: 67890})) RETURN p
```

I'm not sure where to start. Is there something that can be improved about how I am writing my queries? Is there something I can improve on my Neo4J setup/properties? Is this data set too large?

For context, I am using 32GB RAM machine. Your input would be most appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How are you using your DB? (Through the web, or neo4j-shell?)  There may be relevance on cache warmup here.  Have you tried issuing the same query repeatedly and is it faster the second time?   Also, are you using any indexes?  At least you should be indexing `:Person(id)`  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html

Comment: I've been querying it through the web on the dashboard they provide. I haven't even gotten around to letting it complete one time because it seems like its just taking way too long (I don't have the patience for it and for simple queries I wonder if there is something wrong). I set up auto-indexing in the neo4j properties.

Comment: Depending on how your data is connected, you might be asking a really complicated query there, and you're saying it has to sift through 65 million relationships (potentially).  You might want to check out server tuning stuff (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-performance.html) and you might want to make sure there are indexes at least on person name and person ID, because that's how you're matching.   Keep in mind that if you don't give the database hints on how to find things fast (indexes) it has to search ALL person nodes

Comment: Your data set is not too large for neo4j to handle, but I can't tell if you've set up other things appropriately or even how long you are waiting.  How fast do you expect this query to come back?

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look over server performance settings. Do you have specific recommendations for me based on my question as to what I should be setting various values? I would expect this query to come back in less than 1 minutes.

Comment: At a minimum, do those indexes I mentioned above.  Configure the dbms to have more memory than default if possible, and "warm up the database" - do some sample queries just for your target nodes alone.  When the DB starts from cold, your first queries will be slower.  As it progressively caches more stuff, they'll get better.

Comment: Can't tell you whether 1 min is reasonable or not because I don't know how your data is shaped. That sounds low.  I'd give it at least 10-20 before you conclude nothing is happening, particularly if you just started the DB - but this depends quite a bit on how many paths there are between those nodes

Comment: I warmed up the DB as recommended here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632421/can-neo4j-community-edition-start-in-warm-up] using the query match (n)-[r]-() return count(n). That took approximately 13 minutes to execute. I was then able to run shortestPath in milliseconds. If I have 19GB of data, what is the minimum amount of memory I can use?

Comment: To figure your cache size, read this and calculate accordingly.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html